# Record missing when inserting high volume records into azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am trying to insert 100K records from a blob storage (tab delimited file)into a azure table storage using Azure Function. The insertion of those records are very unreliable. At times it does insert all the 100K and sometimes as low as 7500 records. I am struggling to understand the reason why it is failing to insert rest of the records. I am not seeing any exception being thrown.  Here is the code that I am using. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here.
This doesnt happen when I run it locally but only happens when the function is published

```
[FunctionName("LargeFileProcessor")]
        public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("%InputContainer%/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureCloudSettings.StorageConnectionString"));

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("adeptra");

            CloudBlockBlob cbb = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await cbb.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
                string[] result = Encoding.
                  ASCII.
                  GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()).
                  Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                var largeFiles = new List<LargeFile>();
                foreach (var str in result)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str.Trim())) continue;
                    var largeFile = MapFlatFile(str);
                    largeFiles.Add(largeFile);
                }
                //Delete the blob
                await cbb.DeleteAsync();
                for (int i = 0; i < largeFiles.Count; i += 100)
                {
                    var items = largeFiles.Skip(i).Take(100);
                    var success = await _service.BulkInsertLargeFileAsync(items);
                    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(success))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("$Failed at loop i:{i} for reason :{success}");
                    }
                }
            }

        }

 public async Task<string> BulkInsertLargeFileAsync(IEnumerable<LargeFile> rows)
        {
            try
            {
                var largeFileEntity = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LargeFileEntity>>(rows);
                var result = await _largeFileDataProvider.BulkAddCommsTemplateAsync(largeFileEntity);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return $"Exception at BulkInsertLargeFileAsync {exception.Message}";
            }
        }



public async Task<IList<TableResult>> BulkAddCommsTemplateAsync(IEnumerable<LargeFileEntity> templates)
        {
            return await _largeRepository.BatchInsertAsync(templates);
        }

public async Task<IList<TableResult>> BatchInsertAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> rows)
        {
            TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

            foreach (var entity in rows)
            {
                batchOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
            }

            var result = await  _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
            return result;
        }
```

-Alan-

**EDIT:**

If I turn off the "elastic scale out" option in azure function(minimum instance  =1 , maximum burst  = 1), then I can see the results are consistent (100K records being inserted all times).

Comment: On the surface your code looks ok to me. Have you checked storage analytics logs?

Comment: The could be because of Table Storage limits.   How many partitions are you writing to?  The limit is 2,000 entities per second per partition up to 20,000 total entities per second.

Comment: Single Partition